# The logic of multiple travelling animations in javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, logic

I have an image of a bug.  I want to make 5 copies of that image fly in from the side of the screen and bounce around the screen and bounce off the sides. I want them to all have different starting positions and different directions.

so I made some a global variables

```
var flyVar;

var flySpeed = 5;
var widthMax = 0;
var heightMax = 0;
var xPosition = 0;
var yPosition = 0;
var xDirection = "";
var yDirection = "";
var bugFly;

var count = 1;
var bug = "bug";
```

I have a function called `setBugs()` that I use to set the value of widthMax and heightMax depending on the size of the users screen.

I have a bugStartingPlace function to set the initial starting place for each bug. I won't post the whole function but it does the same for "bug1" through "bug5", giving them different values.

```
function bugStartingPlace(bugName) {
//Accepts string as argument and sets the starting position and starting direction of each bug. 
    if (bugName == "bug1") {
        xPosition = 0;
        yPosition = 100;
        xDirection = "right";
        yDirection = "up";
    }
}
```

I have a function called flyBug() that does the animation and sets the position of the image. It consists of a bunch of statements like this. I know it works because I can make it work with 1 bug. The problem is doing it with 5 bugs.

```
function flyBug() { 
     if (xDirection == "right" && xPosition > (widthMax - document.getElementById("bugImage").width - flySpeed))
         xDirection = "left";
<!--More flow control statements are here-->

document.getElementById("bug1").style.left = xPosition + "px";
document.getElementById("bug1").style.top = yPosition + "px";
<!-- More statements are here that set the position of the image -->

}
```

So, I need some way to get the animation going with the body onload() event. One problem is that setInterval does not allow functions that contain parameters. So I can't put multiple statements in the body onload event that pass "bug1" as a parameter to this function, "bug2" as a parameter to this function and so on. That's why I made the global count variable. That way, any time I need to change the name of the bug, I change the name of count and then do

```
bug = bug + count;
```

But that adds a lot of complexity. I need the name of the bug for the bugStartingPlace() function, so I need to change the value of count and also change the value of bug before I use that function. Once I use the bugStartingPlace() function, that changes the value of the global variables. Then I need to use flyBug() before I change the value of bug again.

I guess one of the problems is that I'm using global variables for direction and position even though I have multiple bugs. It works fine for one bug but not for multiple bugs.

Can anyone give me tips on how the logic of this program should work?

Comment: All bugs are using the same global variables?

Comment: you _should_ be OOP technique for this one https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

setInterval allows, like setTimeout, the use of parameters in the function BUT:

```
setInterval(funcName(param1,param2...), 100);
```

wont work. Youll get it to work like that:

```
var func = function () { funcName(param1,param2..); }

setInterval(func, 100);
```

To understand that part of javascript, read through dougles crockfords explanation of functions, he tells about this very clear and deep. [Link to a video of him](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya4UHuXNygM)

**EDIT:** Sry i understood your question wrong...

The problem why it wont work is, like you figured out the global vars. You could just make bug an object. His actions will then be methods, which can contain a function and so on. If you then initialize a new bug (you can do this a thousand times then), all the vars stay in the object, without conflicting each other. This is a secure way to provide solidness of your code.

You could do it very simple, with nested functions.

Another way would be, to send the name of the bug vie parameter to the, for example, fly function. And the only work in that function with the parameter given to it.